# Plot x-values without y-values in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Plotting y-values in pyplot is easy, given a list of `y_values = [0, 1, 4, 9]`, pyplot automatically plots this using

```
plt.plot(y_values)
plt.show()
```

As pyplot automatically enumerates these using `[0,1,2,3]`. However, given a list of `x_values`, is there a way to automatically plot these without providing y-values? e.g. let pyplot automatically enumerating them?

I've tried

```
plt.plot(x=x_values); plt.plot(xdata=x_values)
```

However none of these seem to work. Of course, one way would be to flip the axes, but is there a simpler way I've overlooked?

Comment: You could, of course, create these y values yourself using `numpy.arange()`

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that would work of course, but it would be reasonable to assume that if I don't have to do it for `y_values`, I shouldn't have to do it for `x_values`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The x and y arguments in [`pyplot.plot(*args, **kwargs)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) are positional arguments. According to the documentation, e.g.

```
plot(x, y)        # plot x and y using default line style and color
plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers
plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
```

Now, how would pyplot know that if you specify a single argument, you would want it to be interpreted as the ordinate instead of the coordinate? It's simply not possible the way the function is written.

A solution to plot the index against some list is to supply the index as `y` argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = [0, 1, 4, 9]
plt.plot(x_values, range(len(x_values)))
plt.show()
```